# Can I upload a PDF attachment in a list and edit/save in the browser?

Tags: list, document-library, attachments, file, pdf

Can we edit PDFs directly as an attachment?

This is probably impossible, but is there a way to upload a PDF as an attachment, make changes to that PDF in the browser, and save it to the attachments without downloading it?

We have users that aren't techy and we wanted changes to be easy.

Document libraries and document sets seem more difficult for the user so we wanted to stay with a simple list.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

This is not possible using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint.

Comment: What about non OOTB ways? Like a script running on the edit form? Mind you i don't have SharePoint designer, access to central admin, PowerShell script, access to the hive or root.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to edit PDFs directly as an attachment in the browser. You have to download, edit & then re-attach (upload) the PDF.